# CSS - Superfish, how to float 4th level of dropdown

Tags: css, superfish

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wTNxH/

**Problem:** Try to hover over next menu items: menu item 1 -> >menu item666 -> menu item
You'll notice that next drop down is not floated to the left as it should be, but instead its displayed bellow "menu item".
I believe that problem is somewhere here:

```
.sf-navbar ul ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

**Question:** How to float it to be next to "menu item"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this:

```
.sf-navbar ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```